# SFMC > Cloud page > Smart capture > Field size

Tags: marketing-cloud, smart-capture

I've created a cloud page, and added a smart capture form.

I want to change the size of the fields - the look of it. I want to increase the size of only one field while keeping others the same.

Any code/solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `textarea` propert in HTML to specify your field length

Click on the `"specific interest field" in the canvas > Go to HTML editor tab > Change the input type from Text to TextAread`

Below is an example for one field called 'CustomerID' where you can have a bigger area to enter text.

```
<div class="smartcapture-controls"><div class="sc-formfield-label"><label for="CustomerID">CustomerID</label></div>
<div class=""><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="CustomerID"></textarea></div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: HI Naveen
Thank you for this.. I put the code in a couple of places within the code but it didn't work [refer new screenshot in my question]

Comment: Hi @PrekshaRathore don't put in <Div>, use it in <input> tag.

Comment: I did, and it didn't change there too..

Comment: I have tested in my instance it worked fine. It could be due to cache issue. Try to clear up your cache and try the same in Firefox browser. Just to confirm, you are expecting the field not to occupy more than 100 characters right?

Comment: Hi Naveen
I'm trying to increase box size for one field, and keep all the others the same. Some fields will have a small box and others will have a large box. I don't know how to increase that field box size, while keep the others small/same.

Comment: I thought you are concerned about the length of field. I have updated the answer as per your latest comment. Please have a look.

Comment: @PrekshaRathore did you tried with my answer? This should definitely solve your questions

Comment: Hi Naveen
I just checked the new coding and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome @PrekshaRathore!. Please mark it is as a right answer so that it helps others in future.

Comment: Hi Naveen, when I used this ampscript, what ended up happening is, that everytime someone pressed 'Enter' to right another line in a specific field box - the output (when I exported the DE) came as follows - same field answer in two different rows and different columns.